# Git pathspecs difference in behavior between linux (wsl) and windows

Tags: linux, windows, git, command-line-interface

I do not understand why the same command works on linux and not on windows. Is the pathspecs syntax differ or there is a problem on the git windows version?

On windows (git version 2.31.1.windows.1)

```
git status -- 'src/test.js'
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

On linux (wsl: git version 2.25.1)

```
git status -- 'src/test.js'
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   src/test.js
```

A classic `git status` gives the same result between linux and windows.

Comment: Check  `git diff`. The file has changed in linux. Perhaps one of those totally unexpected EOL changes?

Comment: nop, in windows if I do a `git status` (without a pathspecs) I got the file as `modified`

Comment: I'm also guessing the EOL characters may be responsible. Maybe git's core.autocrlf setting also has something to do with it. Could you check the config in both consoles: `git config --list --show-origin |grep autocrlf`.

Comment: @schilli `git config --list --show-origin |grep autocrlf` return nothing (ps it's the same directory mount in both windows and linux wsl, so no difference here). And I checked, there is real difference in file (so not a problem with crlf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you saw on the Git mailing list, this is actually a `cmd.exe` issue: running:

```
git status -- 'src/test.js'
```

passes the literal string:

```
'src/test.js'
```

to Git, rather than passing:

```
src/test.js
```

to Git.  As a result Git is looking for the file name *including the quotes*.  (The easiest solution is to omit the quotes, which are not required on either system for this pathspec: neither has any characters special to any shell or CLI.)

Comment: Yes, indeed, git staff answer me, thx! and for precision `git status -- "src/te st.js"` double quote instead of single quote if space is present in pathspecs argument.